# Do each new System.Threading.Tasks.Task() creates a new thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

I was just trying to figure out as I am using Task object for to have my time taking operation runs in a separate channel. But I wonder do `Task(()=>{...})` is it similar to create `new Thread(new ThreadStart(()=>{....}))` ?

Comment: Tasks uses ThreadPool,not thread

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: No. Tasks are executed  via a thread pool.  Here'r a blog about this: [Threads vs. Tasks](http://blog.slaks.net/2013-10-11/threads-vs-tasks/): A task does not create its own OS thread. Instead, tasks are executed by a TaskScheduler; the default scheduler simply runs on the ThreadPool

Comment: indirectly you mean to say when I create a new Task it instantiate/create/load a new thread from thread pool??

Comment: @BreakHead If there is an idle thread available in the threadpool, it will use that thread. If there are not currently any idle threads in the threadpool, a new thread WILL be created. When there are a few threads lying idle in the threadpool, some of them will be stopped. (This is somewhat of a simplification, but you get the idea.)

Comment: @Matt Thanks, one last query, Do this thread pool is maintained by .Net itself ?

Comment: This is one of many possibilities, but certainly not the only one.  Not all tasks, even tasks created using the `Task` constructor, are executed on the thread pool.

Answer (score 3):

A `Task` represents a **promise** of work to be completed some time in the future.

There are a couple of options to how a `Task` gets created:

1. Using `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew` without any flags - This will queue work on the .NET ThreadPool, as stated.
2. Using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and specifying the `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning` - This will signal the `TaskScheduler` to use a new thread instead of a ThreadPool thread.
3. When using `async-await` feature of C#-5, also known as `Promise Tasks`. When you `await` on a method returning a `Task` or a `Task<T>`, they may not use any threading mechanism, either ThreadPool or `new Thread` to do their work as they *may* use a purely asynchronous API, meaning they will **continue to execute on the thread which executed them**, and will yield control back to calling method once hitting the first`await` keyword.
4. Thanks to Servy for this one. Another options for execution is creating a custom `TaskScheduler` and passing it to `Task.Factory.StartNew`. A custom `TaskScheduler` will give you fine-grained control over the execution of your `Task`

All these options come to show that a `Task` is merely a promise, and there are many forms in which you may fulfill that promise. A Thread is a means to an end, while a `Task` is the unit of work we want done.

Comment: To your point #3, there are indeed tasks that can be created that do represent that, but they are not created through the use of `await`.  Any code following an `await` is code run on some actual thread somewhere.  `await` is merely a tool that lets you run some code when a task finishes; the task *being* awaited may or may not involve the use of an actual thread.  There are also other options besides just 1 and 2 when using `Run` for further options still.

Comment: @Servy I've edited point 3 to make it clear as for what i ment. As for further options, care to elaborate what i missed?

Comment: You missed a custom task scheduler

Answer (score 2):

Possibly.  It depends.

- By default `Task` objects created using `Task.Run`, `Task.Factory.StartNew`, or using the `Task` constructor, will use the default `TaskSchedluer`, which will schedule the delegate to be run in the thread pool.
- A non-default `TaskScheduler` can be used to schedule the task to run on any thread that you define using that scheduler.  You could define it to run in the UI thread, in it's own new thread, in a pool of threads besides the .NET thread pool, not at all, or whatever else you want.
- You can create a `Task` using a `TaskCompletionSource`, in which there is no need for a thread to exist at all.  The `Task` doesn't even need to represent the completion of a delegate.  It can represent any operation that finishes at some time in the future, possibly with a result.  It *could* involve some code running on a thread, or it could represent an inherently asynchronous operation such as IO, user behavior, an event firing, a composition of various other tasks, or anything else that you want to create.